# PHP - How to check whether a year is bisect (i.e. a leap year)?

Tags: php

How can I check whether a year is bisect (i.e. a leap year) in php ?

Comment: Years are 'leap years', if they are divisible by 4 (or 400), but not 100.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use PHP's [date()](http://php.net/date) function to do this...

```
// L will return 1 if it is a leap year, 0 otherwise
echo date('L');

// use your own timestamp
echo date('L', strtotime('last year'));

// for specific year
$year = 1999;
$leap = date('L', mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $year));
echo $year . ' ' . ($leap ? 'is' : 'is not') . ' a leap year.';
```

Let me know if this does this trick for you, Cheers!

**UPDATE:** Added Example for Specific Year

Comment: Just to let you know, 2400 will return 0. So it fails there.

Answer (score 17):

A **bisect year** is another name for a **leap year**. Use the `L` formatter, where `$year` is the year you are testing:

```
echo (date('L', strtotime("$year-01-01")) ? 'Yes' : 'No');
```

> To adjust the discordance between the
>   calendar and seasons, the Julian
>   calendar used the calculations of the
>   Greek astronomer Sosigene and was
>   based on the adoption of a 365.25 days
>   year: 3 years of 365 days followed by
>   a 366 days year, the supplementary day
>   being added always after the 24th of
>   February (sexto ante calendas Martiis
>   = the sixth day before the March calends) being called bis sexto (the
>   sixth day bis), hence the names of
>   bisect year and bisect day for the
>   leap day. The year was divided in 12
>   months, which alternated 31 and 30
>   days and February had, in normal
>   years, 29 days and 30 days in bisect
>   years.
>
> Later, when the eighth month was
>   dedicated to the emperor Augustus
>   (August), this month was made of 31
>   days to match July, the month
>   dedicated to Julius Caesar. That's why
>   February was made of 28 days, having
>   29 days in bisect years.

http://news.softpedia.com/news/The-History-of-Modern-Calendar-and-Bisect-Year-79892.shtml

Answer (score 14):

```
function is_leap_year($year)
{
    return ((($year % 4) == 0) && ((($year % 100) != 0) || (($year %400) == 0)));
}
```

Comment: Note that this code is 4.9 times faster than other ones given here (using date conversions) and output the exact same result from year 101 to 99999.

Answer (score 4):

Using the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
$year = 2000;
$isLeap = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y', $year)->format('L') === "1";
var_dump($isLeap); // bool(true)
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem of checking if year is leap year is, if julian or gregorian calendar is used.

Meanwhile year in julian calendar has 365,25, year in gregorian calendar has 365,2422. So, gregorian year is of 11 minutes shorter than julian. And general rule for leap years (year/4 must be integer) is not valid at all times.

```
Year/4
Year/100 & Year/400
```

So most of years when Year/100 are not leap years.

Also, there is one another important condition for this checking.

```
Year >= 1583
```

As gregorian calendar was ordered to use in 1582 and this year was affected by changes caused by beginning of usage of this calendar (there was Thursday 4th October and then 15th October - days between were *deleted*), 1583 is the first year that is countable as fully gregorian (in gregorian calendar). But I decided to not test this condition, as this condition should be probably tested prior to testing of leap year - if it is not sure if year is counted in accordance with gregorian calendar.

---

For both calendars it is possible to write own function (or standalone static method) and result should be probably the same as if PHP's class would be used.

And also, usage of your own function/method will take shorter code.

```
public static function Is_LeapYear($Year = 1583)
{
    $LeapYear = FALSE;

    if(CheckTypes::Is_Integer($Year / 4))
    {
        if(CheckTypes::Is_Integer($Year / 100) && !CheckTypes::Is_Integer($Year / 400))
        {
            $LeapYear = FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            $LeapYear = TRUE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $LeapYear = FALSE;
    }

    return $LeapYear;
}
```

`CheckTypes` is my own class for multiple type checking (else methods allow to multiple type checking). `Is_Integer` is (due to one type checking) equal to `is_integer` from PHP in-built functions. So, `CheckTypes::Is_Integer($Year / 4)` may be replaced with `is_integer($Year / 4)` and result will be the same.

This counting of leap year is in accorance with gregorian calendar, not julian.

Comment: Not a great solution since it takes way too much code for something this simple, but upvoted to recognize your amazing research job.

Answer (score 2):

If you care about performance, the faster way is:

```
!($year % 4) && ($year % 100 || !($year % 400))
```

It returns the exact same result than:

```
(bool) date('L', mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $year))
```

From year 101 to 999999 but it's about 30 times faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
$isLeapYear = fn($year) => $year % 400 === 0 || ($year % 100 !== 0 && $year % 4 === 0)
```