# Getting the amount of leap days in a date range

Tags: php, datetime, php-5.5

I have the following 2 dates:

```
$start = new DateTime('2008-06-01');
$end = new DateTime('2016-12-31');
$diff = $start->diff($end);
```

Now the `$diff->days` gives `3135 days`, but that includes 2 *leap days*.
How should I calculate the amount of February 29's between the `$start` and `$end` dates ?

This is for an invoicing system, where leap days should never be counted (company policy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if it's a leap year:

The only difference between [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680115/php-how-to-check-whether-a-year-is-bisect-i-e-a-leap-year) and this one is that where they used $year you write a loop where $i begins at the year you want to start and ends at the end year (:

Comment: Sure that works, though I feel as it's quite inefficient. Do you know of any other approach on this ?

Comment: No sorry, this is the only way to comes to mind. By the way, if you plan on using the leap years more often it might be a good idea to store them in an array.