# Leap year friendly year/month/day select option tags with PHP embedded

Tags: php, html, forms, date, leap-year

I'm trying to write codes with PHP to enable leap year friendly select option tags. For example, you pick a year, then it checks if it is a leap year or not, then it shows a pull down menu (select option tags) of days preceded by another select option tags of 12 months. PHP codes are embedded in HTML. Here is my failed attempt below (I'm new to PHP):

```
<form method="post">    
<select name="year">
 <option value="" selected>Pick a year</option><!--Default-->
 <option value="2016">2016</option>
 <option value="2017">2017</option>
 <option value="2018">2018</option>
 <option value="2019">2019</option>
 <option value="2020">2020</option>
</select>
<select name="month">
 <option value="" selected>Pick a month</option><!--Default-->
 <!--Show all 12 months-->  
 <?php for( $i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++ ): ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
 <?php endfor; ?>
</select>
<select name="day">
 <option value="" selected>Pick a day</option><!--Default-->
 <!--Show dates depending on the conditions below:-->
 <?php
 if ( $month == 1 || 3 || 5 || 7 || 8 || 10 || 12 )
 {
    //Show dates until 31
    for ( $i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++ )
    {
 ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
 <?php
    }
 }
 elseif ( $month == 2 )
 {
    //Leap year
    if ( $year != "" && $year % 4 == 0 && $year % 100 == 0 && $year % 400 == 0 )
    {
        //Show dates until 29
        for ( $i = 1; $i <= 29; $i++ )
        {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
            <?php
        }
    }
    //Regular year (Non-leap year)
    else 
    {
        //Show dates until 28
        for ( $i = 1; $i <= 28; $i++ )
        {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
            <?php
        }
     }
}
elseif ( $month == 4 || 6 || 9 || 11 )
{
    //Show dates until 30
    for ( $i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++ )
    {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
 }
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**Notes:**

I understand that the above is the incomplete code and it doesn't work. Besides, I don't know how to define `$year` or `$month` or `$day` from the select tags. Should I do it like this? If so, where should I put it?

```
<?php 
if( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" )    
{
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $day = $_POST['day'];

    //The rest of the php code?
}
?>
```

Preferably, I do not want to show years by using `for` loops as in months and days. I would like to do it manually this time (sorry, but if you suggest I should use the `for` loop, I appreciate your advise).

I wrote `$year =! ""` in the leap year February `if` block because I want to evade the empty default values from being counted.

I warmly welcome your suggestions and corrections, please help me out :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to use some third-party JavaScript datepicker, rather than reinventing the wheel? [This](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), or [this](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - How to check whether a year is bisect (i.e. a leap year)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680115/php-how-to-check-whether-a-year-is-bisect-i-e-a-leap-year)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know about leap year:

```
/**
 * In the Gregorian calendar 3 criteria must be taken into account to identify leap years:
 *  1. The year is evenly divisible by 4;
 *  2. If the year can be evenly divided by 100, it is NOT a leap year, unless;
 *  3. The year is also evenly divisible by 400. Then it is a leap year.
 *
 * @param $year integer
 * @return bool
 */
private static function isLeapYear($year)
{
    // the rule was applied after 1582
    if ($year > 1582) {
        if (($year % 400 == 0 && $year % 100 != 0) || ($year % 4 == 0))
        {
            //"It is a leap year"
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
            //"It is not a leap year"
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680115/php-how-to-check-whether-a-year-is-bisect-i-e-a-leap-year/5680160#5680160

Answer (score 0):

This won't work:

```
( $month == 1 || 3 || 5 || 7 || 8 || 10 || 12 )
```

This will only check that `$month == 1`, then the other conditions will be evaluated to true because the integers are evaluated to `true` (and PHP can't compare a variable to booleans with this code).

It looks like you're trying to get the number of days per month. This can be done easily with `DateTime::Format()` that use the [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) format:

`t` returns the *Number of days in the given month*:

```
$dt = new Datetime('2016-02-15');
print $dt->format('t');
// display "29"
```

[Example](https://3v4l.org/Rn0sA).

`L` returns the `1` if a year is leap, `0` otherwise:

```
$dt = new Datetime('2016-02-15');
print $dt->format('L');
// display "1"
$dt = new Datetime('2015-02-15');
print $dt->format('L');
// display "0"
```

[Example](https://3v4l.org/UYfgl).

You should probably don't care about the inputs and display all the years, the 12 months and 31 days per month and check the date with [`checkdate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) once the data have been submitted.