# Leap year and non leap year into separate tables

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-modal, leap-year

This code will display the the leap year and non leap year from 1991 to 2100, I tried to make table one for leap year and other for non leap year but I failed.

How can I bring it in table format or in a grid system? This is for academic study.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Leap Year</title>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php  
        function isLeap($year) {
        return ((($year % 4) == 0) && ((($year % 100) != 0)));
        }

            for($year=1991; $year<=2100; $year++)  
            {  
                If (isLeap($year))  
                {   
                    $leap="$year : LEAP YEAR <br/>";
                    //echo "<div class='col-sm-12'>" . $leap . "</div>";
                    echo $leap;
                }  
                else  
                {  
                    $nonLeap="$year : Not leap year <br/>";  
                    //echo "<div class='col-sm-6'>" . $nonLeap ."</div>";       
                    echo $nonLeap;           
                }  
            }
        ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Show me what you have tried ?

Comment: So, you want two tables: one with just the list of leap year, and one without them? Inside that `for` loop you can store them in two array, and after that build your tables with them. Try something, then update your answer.

Comment: i dont know how to convert it into an array thats the problem and print it @Federkun

Comment: i m supposed to leap year from year which my bro told me to, i did it. But now he told me to show it separately like leap year in one table and non leap year in one table or using grid system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your isLeap function is wrong. You also can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680115/php-how-to-check-whether-a-year-is-bisect-i-e-a-leap-year).

```
function isLeap($year) {
    return ((($year % 4) == 0) && ((($year % 100) != 0) || (($year % 400) == 0)));
}

for($year=1991; $year<=2100; $year++)  
{  
    if (isLeap($year))  
    {   
        $leaps[] = $year;
    }  
    else  
    {  
        $nonLeaps[] = $year;
    }
}

echo '<table><tr>';
foreach($leaps as $y)
{
  echo '<td>' . $y . '</td>';
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Thanks for the help, I got it. This is the answer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Leap Year</title>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .table-border{
            border:1px solid black;
            margin-top: 20px !important;
            margin-bottom: 20px !important; 
        }
        header{
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 50px;
            border: 1px solid;
            margin-left: 28px;
            margin-right: 28px;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<header>Leap Year and Non-Leap year...</header>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#table.display').DataTable();
             "pagingType": "full_numbers"
        } );    
    </script>

    <?php  
        function isLeap($year) {
        return ((($year % 4) == 0) && ((($year % 100) != 0) || (($year % 400) == 0)));
        }

        for($year=1900; $year<=2100; $year++)  
        {  
            If (isLeap($year))  
            {   
                $leaps[] = $year;
            }  
            else  
            {  
                $nonLeaps[] = $year;
            }
        }
        echo'<div class="col-sm-12">';
        echo'<div class="col-sm-6">';
        echo'<table style="width: 100%" id="DataTables_Table_0" class=" table-border display dataTable"><tr><th>Leap Year</th></tr>';

                foreach($leaps as $y){

                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>' . $y . '</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';

                    }

        echo '</table></div>';

        echo'<div class="col-sm-6">';
        echo'<table style="width: 100%" id="DataTables_Table_0" class="table-border display dataTable"><tr><th>Non-Leap Year</th></tr>';

                    foreach ($nonLeaps as $ny) {

                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>' . $ny . '</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';

                        }
        echo '</table></div>';
        echo '</div>';
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```